# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mkstudent.classes_teacher' doesn't exist (SQL: select `teachers`.*, `classes_teacher`.`cla

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

here is my Classes model

```
class Classes extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = [
        'name','course_catagory_id','teacher_id'
    ];

    public function coursecatagory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CourseCatagory::class);
    }
    public function teacher()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class);
    }
}
```

and migrations

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('course_catagory_id');
            $table->integer('teacher_id');
            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and create classes page

```
  <div class="card-body">
            @if(session()->has('success'))
             <div class="alert alert-success">
                 {{session()->get('success')}}
               </div>
             @endif
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('courses.store')}}">
               @csrf 
               
            <table class="table table-boreder">
               <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <td>
                     <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                     <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">
                     
                  </td>
               </tr>
                                  
               </table>
          </form>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and classes index page

```
<div class="card-body">
        @if($data->count()>0)
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>Course Catagory</th>
                <th>
                    Teacher
                </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($data as $d)
                <tr>
                    
                    <td>
                        {{$d->name}}

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{$d->coursecatagory['name']}}

                    </td>
                    
                    
                    <td>
                    <a href="#">
                        {{$d->teacher['first_name']}}
                    </a>
                    </td>
            
                    
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        @else
        <h3 class="text-center">No class Yet!</h3>
        @endif
        
    </div>
```

and when i create a new class it saved in the database but dose not restricted to the index view and when i tray to see the index view only the class name is displayed the other fields are not dispalyed and the error face the error

Comment: Why is the question tagged Laravel 5? Surely you are not using this old software?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you update your Classes model with a `$table` protected property such that:

```
protected $table = 'classes_teacher'
```

Or, whatever the table name is supposed to be ?

Comment: the teacher name is working but still the coursecatagory name is not working

Answer (score 0):

> 'mkstudent.classes_teacher' doesn't exist (SQL: select `teachers`.*,
> `classes_teacher`.`cla ...

The problem is that classes_teacher is not plural. I should be named `classes_teachers`. But you can add in your model the modified name.

`protected $table = "classes_teacher"`

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up your relationships. You declare `Classes`->`Teacher` as `BelongsToMany`, so Laravel is trying to find a pivot table to build the relationship. But your migration shows that `classes` has a `teacher_id` column, suggesting it should be simply `BelongsTo`.

```php
class Classes extends Model
{
    public function teacher()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class);
    }
}
```

You've also done migrations wrong, with foreign keys not set up as such, and also using the wrong column type. It should look like this:

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->foreignId('course_catagory_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('teacher_id')->constrained();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Your other migrations would need to be redone in a similar fashion.

And, you've misspelled "category."